# Trigger Stripe SCA redirection for authentication

Tags: php, stripe-payments, 3d-secure

I have this stripe file `StripePayment.php`

```
<?php

require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

use \Stripe\Stripe;
use \Stripe\Customer;
use \Stripe\ApiOperations\Create;
use \Stripe\Charge;

class StripePayment
{

    private $apiKey;

    private $stripeService;

    public function __construct()
    {
        require_once "config.php";
        $this->apiKey = STRIPE_SECRET_KEY;
        $this->stripeService = new \Stripe\Stripe();
        $this->stripeService->setVerifySslCerts(false);
        $this->stripeService->setApiKey($this->apiKey);
    }

    public function addCustomer($customerDetailsAry)
    {
        
        $customer = new Customer();
        
        $customerDetails = $customer->create($customerDetailsAry);
        
        return $customerDetails;
    }

    public function chargeAmountFromCard($cardDetails)
    {
        $customerDetailsAry = array(
            'email' => $cardDetails['email'],
            'source' => $cardDetails['token']
        );
        $customerResult = $this->addCustomer($customerDetailsAry);
        $charge = new Charge();
        $cardDetailsAry = array(
            'customer' => $customerResult->id,
            'amount' => $cardDetails['amount']*100 ,
            'currency' => $cardDetails['currency_code'],
            'description' => $cardDetails['item_name'],
            'metadata' => array(
                'order_id' => $cardDetails['item_number']
            )
        );
        $result = $charge->create($cardDetailsAry);

        return $result->jsonSerialize();
    }
}
```

and i am charging the card like this

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
ini_set('display_startup_errors', '1');
error_reporting(E_ALL);

require_once "config.php";

if (!empty($_POST["token"])) {
    require_once 'StripePayment.php';
    $stripePayment = new StripePayment();
    
    $stripeResponse = $stripePayment->chargeAmountFromCard($_POST);
    
    require_once "DBController.php";
    $dbController = new DBController();
    
    $amount = $stripeResponse["amount"] /100;
    
    $param_type = 'ssdssss';
    $param_value_array = array(
        $_POST['email'],
        $_POST['item_number'],
        $amount,
        $stripeResponse["currency"],
        $stripeResponse["balance_transaction"],
        $stripeResponse["status"],
        json_encode($stripeResponse)
    );
```

This code is able to charge cards but can't charge cards where 3D/SCA is required i.e European cards.

My question, is there a way i can request stripe to redirect the user to the card issuing bank for authentication so that the user can authorize the transaction?

My stripe form code looks like this

```
<form id="frmStripePayment" action=""
                method="post">
                <div class="field-row">
                    <label>Card Holder Name</label> <span
                        id="card-holder-name-info" class="info"></span><br>
                    <input type="text" id="name" name="name"
                        class="demoInputBox">
                </div>
                <div class="field-row">
                    <label>Email</label> <span id="email-info"
                        class="info"></span><br> <input type="text"
                        id="email" name="email" class="demoInputBox">
                </div>
                <div class="field-row">
                    <label>Card Number</label> <span
                        id="card-number-info" class="info"></span><br> <input
                        type="text" id="card-number" name="card-number"
                        class="demoInputBox">
                </div>
                <div class="field-row">
                    <div class="contact-row column-right">
                        <label>Expiry Month / Year</label> <span
                            id="userEmail-info" class="info"></span><br>
                        <select name="month" id="month"
                            class="demoSelectBox">
                <option value="02">02</option>
                            <option value="03">03</option>
                            <option value="04">04</option>
                            <option value="05">05</option>
                            <option value="06">06</option>
                            <option value="07">07</option>
                            <option value="08">08</option>
                            <option value="08">08</option>
                            <option value="08">08</option>
                            <option value="09">09</option>
                            <option value="10">10</option>
                            <option value="11">11</option>
                            <option value="12">12</option>
                        </select> <select name="year" id="year"
                            class="demoSelectBox">
                            <option value="21">2021</option>
                            <option value="22">2022</option>
                            <option value="23">2023</option>
                            <option value="24">2024</option>
                            <option value="25">2025</option>
                            <option value="26">2026</option>
                            <option value="27">2027</option>
                            <option value="28">2028</option>
                            <option value="29">2029</option>
                            <option value="30">2030</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="contact-row cvv-box">
                        <label>CVC</label> <span id="cvv-info"
                            class="info"></span><br> <input type="text"
                            name="cvc" id="cvc"
                            class="demoInputBox cvv-input">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input type="submit" name="pay_now" value="Submit"
                        id="submit-btn" class="btnAction"
                        onClick="stripePay(event);">

                    <div id="loader">
                        <img alt="loader" src="LoaderIcon.gif">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <input type='hidden' name='amount' value='1100'> <input
                    type='hidden' name='currency_code' value='USD'> <input
                    type='hidden' name='item_name' value='Solidroof Product'>
                <input type='hidden' name='item_number'
                    value='SCA#Test'>
            </form>


    <script>
function cardValidation () {
    var valid = true;
    var name = $('#name').val();
    var email = $('#email').val();
    var cardNumber = $('#card-number').val();
    var month = $('#month').val();
    var year = $('#year').val();
    var cvc = $('#cvc').val();

    $("#error-message").html("").hide();

    if (name.trim() == "") {
        valid = false;
    }
    if (email.trim() == "") {
           valid = false;
    }
    if (cardNumber.trim() == "") {
           valid = false;
    }

    if (month.trim() == "") {
            valid = false;
    }
    if (year.trim() == "") {
        valid = false;
    }
    if (cvc.trim() == "") {
        valid = false;
    }

    if(valid == false) {
        $("#error-message").html("All Fields are required").show();
    }

    return valid;
}
//set your publishable key
Stripe.setPublishableKey("<?php echo STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY; ?>");

//callback to handle the response from stripe
function stripeResponseHandler(status, response) {
    if (response.error) {
        //enable the submit button
        $("#submit-btn").show();
        $( "#loader" ).css("display", "none");
        //display the errors on the form
        $("#error-message").html(response.error.message).show();
    } else {
        //get token id
        var token = response['id'];
        //insert the token into the form
        $("#frmStripePayment").append("<input type='hidden' name='token' value='" + token + "' />");
        //submit form to the server
        $("#frmStripePayment").submit();
    }
}
function stripePay(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var valid = cardValidation();

    if(valid == true) {
        $("#submit-btn").hide();
        $( "#loader" ).css("display", "inline-block");
        Stripe.createToken({
            number: $('#card-number').val(),
            cvc: $('#cvc').val(),
            exp_month: $('#month').val(),
            exp_year: $('#year').val()
        }, stripeResponseHandler);

        //submit from callback
        return false;
    }
}
</script>
```

According to the docs on how to manually require the user to be redirected to the bank url for further authentication https://stripe.com/docs/payments/3d-secure#manual-three-ds

```
next_action: {
    type: 'redirect_to_url',
    redirect_to_url: {
      url: 'https://hooks.stripe.com/...',
      return_url: 'https://example.com'
    }
}
```

does the stripe sdk automatically know the bank url to redirect to or who feeds that info?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bank-hosted authentication URL is handled by redirecting through that `redirect_to_url.url`, or alternatively is managed automatically when using Stripe's Payment Intent API with `confirmCardPayment` in Stripe.js v3 ([migration guide](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-intents/migration)). If you use `confirmCardPayment`, you yourself don't need to manage the redirect at all. This is the recommendation approach to supporting 3D Secure.

You can [support 3DS using the Sources API](https://stripe.com/docs/sources/three-d-secure), but this is deprecated and no longer recommended.

Comment: One thing  i hae come to appreciate from the stripe docs is that almost everything in there is deprecated and the examples don't ever work and when they do, a few months later, it breaks.

Comment: Its extremely frustrating to work with stripe payments.

Comment: I highly recommend looking at the newer Payment Intent integration pattern with `confirmCardPayment` -- this makes handling 3DS very painless.

Comment: I have and i made it to show the 3D dialog as i wanted. However, when saving a card and i trigger the 3Ds dialog when using setup intent, after authentication, i am unable to add a customer.

Answer (score 0):

Specify the return_url as return_url:window.location.href it will take back to the page where the payment started.